# Stack around variable 'data' was corrupted

Tags: c++, text, fonts, stack, sfml

I'm using SFML. I'm trying to write some text on the screen. Whenever I close the application I get "Stack around variable 'data' was corrupted" error, but I don't see anything wrong with the code.

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main() {
    RenderWindow win(VideoMode(640, 480), "", Style::None);

    Font lucida;
    lucida.loadFromFile("lucon.ttf");
    Text data;
    data.setCharacterSize(12);
    data.setColor(Color(180, 180, 180));
    data.setFont(lucida);
    data.setPosition(Vector2f(10, 10));
    data.setStyle(Text::Bold);
    data.setString("test");

    Event evt;

    double dt = 0.f;
    Clock clock;
    double dwticks = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    double dwnewticks = 0.f;

    while (win.isOpen()) {
        if (win.pollEvent(evt)) {
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Escape)) win.close();
        }
        else {
            dwnewticks = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
            dt = dwnewticks > dwticks ? (dwnewticks - dwticks) / 4000.f : 0.f;
            dwticks = dwnewticks;

            win.clear(Color(0, 0, 0));
            win.draw(data);
            win.display();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the message show up correctly?

Comment: Yes, the message shows up correctly.

Comment: Instead of stuffing a lot of code in main(), refactor to little worker functions that get the job done.  Now you localize the bug and with some luck don't have to wait until program exit before you get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Escape)) win.close();
```

To:

```
if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Escape)){
   win.close();
   break;
}
```